# Passing a Method to a class for EventHandlers

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

Using a separate class which is being made reusable, need to pass it a function which would be called on the click event from the context menu...

Problem : Functions aren't type EventHandlers.... also Different EventHandlers require different paramters inside... e.g. the OnClose for the exit button....

Edit:

In the Class X

```
public void AddMenuItem(String name, EventHandler target )
    {
        MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem();
        newItem.Index = _menuItemIndex++;
        newItem.Text = name;
        newItem.Click += target;

        _contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(newItem);
    }
```

In the Wpf:

```
addToTray.AddMenuItem("&Exit", Exit);
```

I would love it to link to the following method but at this point any method would do fine.

```
private void ShouldIExit(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // checks if the Job is running and if so prompts to continue
        if (_screenCaptureSession.Running())
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Capturing in Progress. Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", "Capturing", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        _screenCaptureSession.Stop();
        _screenCaptureSession.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: it sounds like you'll be creating a debugging nightmare

Comment: @Beth - I am half asleep doing this so yeah pretty much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that your `ShouldIExit` method does not match the `EventHandler` delegate. Try changing it to take a regular `EventArgs` parameter, and see if that works. It's best to avoid reusing the same event handler for different event types. You should encapsulate common code into separate methods, and then have different handlers call that code.

```
private bool CheckExit()
{
    // checks if the Job is running and if so prompts to continue
    if (_screenCaptureSession.Running())
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Capturing in Progress. Are You Sure You Want To Quit?", "Capturing", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    _screenCaptureSession.Stop();
    _screenCaptureSession.Dispose();
    return true;
}

private void ExitButtonClicked(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckExit())
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void ExitMenuItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckExit();
}
```

Comment: Hahah, yeah being dead doesn't help programming :P... Thanks and also you added an exclamation mark in front of a function call "!CheckExit();"

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit vauge, but you could probably do

```
 OnClose += (sender,e) => YourFunction(...)
```

which has the downside that it not possible to remove the eventhandler again if needed

Comment: While it's likely not an issue, it's worth noting that using a lambda expression (or any anonymous method) makes removing it from the event handler very tricky, if not impossible, from the consuming code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, been falling asleep for not getting any sleep last night. i'll edit my question with more clarification.